# d3.js v7 equivalent of d3.scale.ordinal()

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

What is the d3.js v7 equivalent of d3.scale.ordinal() and how would I use it for colour ranges?

In v3.5.11 I could use:

```
var colourScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(["One", "Two", "Three"])
        .range(["#abacab", "#b67a4e", "#5a6fbb"])

        nodeUpdate.select("circle")
            .attr("r", 6.5)
            .attr("fill-opacity", "0.7")
            .attr("stroke-opacity", "1")
            .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return (typeof d._children !== 'undefined') ? (colourScale(findParent(d))) : '#FFF';
            })
            .style("stroke", function(d) {
                    return colourScale(findParent(d));
            });
```

I saw a reference to using [InternMap](https://github.com/mbostock/internmap) as part of the [changes for v7](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/main/CHANGES.md), but it's not clear if this replaces scale.ordinal (and successive versions scaleOrdinal and scaleBand) and how it is used in the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3.scale.ordinal()` was changed to `d3.scaleOrdinal` in [v4](http://d3.scale.ordinal()). [Examples here.](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-scaleordinal)

So now you can write the above as:

```
const colourScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(["One", "Two", "Three"])
        .range(["#abacab", "#b67a4e", "#5a6fbb"])
```

[Working Codesandbox running v7 here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-sunset-1vfkk?file=/index.html)

Hope this is helpful! ✌️

Comment: Yes, Stack Overflow's embedded code editor only goes up to v5 but it's functionally the same -- just to put your mind at ease, the Codesandbox here is running v7 with that colorscale and `scaleOrdinal`. :)

https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-sunset-1vfkk?file=/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same error going from v4 to v7. Below worked for me.

```
const colourScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(
    ["One", "Two", "Three"],
    ["#abacab", "#b67a4e", "#5a6fbb"])

const colourScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(
    [0, 100],
    ["#abacab", "#b67a4e", "#5a6fbb"])
```